# Why do I get an error whenever I pass data from a BR to Main Activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that alerts the main activity whenever a new SMS is received and whenever I get a new SMS the application crashes.

Logcat states this:

```
10-14 15:56:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(27068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 15:56:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(27068): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.testapp.SMSReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Here is a codeblock from the receiver that seems to cause the error

```
Intent passSMStoMain = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                passSMStoMain.putExtra("SENDER", msg_from);
                passSMStoMain.putExtra("MESSAGE", msgBody);
                context.startActivity(passSMStoMain);//this line makes the app crash
```

How am I supposed to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent passSMStoMain = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
passSMStoMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
passSMStoMain.putExtra("SENDER", msg_from);
passSMStoMain.putExtra("MESSAGE", msgBody);
context.startActivity(passSMStoMain);
```

Comment: This fixes it, but can you explain what the problem was? I am still not familiar with "flags."

Answer (score 0):

Try **getApplicationContext()**

```
Intent passSMStoMain = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
passSMStoMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
passSMStoMain.putExtra("SENDER", msg_from);
passSMStoMain.putExtra("MESSAGE", msgBody);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(passSMStoMain);
```